# Жироотталкивающий

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли писать **" жироотталкивающий"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу альтернативы. Слово явно существует, восходит к "отталкивающий жир", "жирозащитный". Написание, следовательно, слитное. Дефисное (и тем более - раздельное) здесь просто невозможно.

Сравните: "водоотталкивающий".

Если сомнения не в орфографии, прошу уточнить.

Comment: А "жирозащитный" есть в словаре?